# Botão flutuante

Tags: android

Como colocar um botão flutuante, tipo o do Gmail, que é pra escrever um novo e-mail, na aplicação?

É possível alterar o ícone deste botão via programação?

Comment: Você pode usar essa biblioteca aqui: https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button Exemplo de uso no próprio repositório: https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button/tree/master/sample

Answer (score 2):

A partir do SDK 21, você pode utilizar o `ViewOutlineProvider`:

1) Crie um layout dentro de uma pasta `layout-v21` no seu projeto, inserindo um `ImageButton`:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingButton"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:contentDescription="description"
    android:background="@drawable/oval_ripple"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />
```

2) crie um `Ripple` simples para dar o efeito no botão (`oval_ripple.xml` na pasta `drawable-v21` de seu projeto):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="?android:colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

3) Agora, em seu código:

```
...
//Verificando se o aparelho está no V21 ou não
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
    initLFloatingButtons();
} else{
    //implementações abaixo
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void initLFloatingButtons() {

    int size = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 56, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    final ViewOutlineProvider viewOutlineProvider = new ViewOutlineProvider() {
        @Override
        public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
            outline.setOval(0, 0, size, size);
        }
    };

    ImageButton floatingButton = ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.floatingButton));
    floatingButton.setOutlineProvider(viewOutlineProvider);
    floatingButton.setClipToOutline(true);
    floatingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Seu evento
        }
    });
}
```

Para você utilizar um Floating Button antes do v21, [recomendo você utilizar este repositório](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button). Você pode importar a biblioteca em seu projeto ou simplesmente selecionar os arquivos que te interessam dentro do repositório.

Para implementar (caso você tenha extraido as classes para seu projeto), você simplesmente:

```
<br.com.seuprojeto.seupackage.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingButton"
    android:layout_width="76dp"
    android:layout_height="76dp"
    android:contentDescription="description"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />
```

E em sua classe:

```
...
FloatingActionButton floatingButton = findViewById(R.id.floatingButton);
floatingButton.setSize(FloatingActionButton.SIZE_NORMAL);
floatingButton.setColorNormalResId(R.color.sua_cor_normal);
floatingButton.setColorPressedResId(R.color.sua_cor_pressionada);
floatingButton.setIcon(R.drawable.seu_drawable);
floatingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Seu evento
    }
});
```

---

## Edit

Utilize o [FloatingActionButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) da [biblioteca de design](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) do próprio Android.

Answer (score 2):

Isso ao xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/stat_notify_chat"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/item_detail_container"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end" />
```

e adicione isto ao código

```
 FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                 // adicione sua ação    
                }
            });
```

Ou inicie um projeto já com o botão pronto

Answer (score 1):

Utilize `FloatingActionButton`, e utlizar da parte gráfica `ShapeDrawable`.

Outra forma mais simples de trocar a imagem ou botão, seria através do `setImageResource`, de acordo com a imagem fazer determinado método.